# Index was outside the bounds of the array: Grocery item list addition

Tags: c#, arrays

I am doing a method where user chooses the amount of grocery items he/she wants to list. That grocery item amount was declared before by intGroceryAmount (parsed from strGroceryAmount)

Now if user wants to add another item to the grocery list, the array size has to be increased by 1, and all the items in the grocery list has to be shown, including the new addition

I tried to add 1 to the array size so that now there is an extra space, and assign that empty space the user input for the new grocery item. Unfortunately, this is where the error occurs

P.S: The loop shown in the end is "supposed" to show all the items in the grocery

```
strNumofPurchaseArray = new string[intGroceryAmount + 1];
System.Console.WriteLine("What is the new item you wish to enter?");
strNewItemInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
strNumofPurchaseArray[intGroceryAmount + 1] = strNewItemInput;

System.Console.WriteLine("\nYour new list of Grocery item is shown below:\n");
while (intNewItemCounter < intGroceryAmount)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Grocery item #" + (intNewItemCounter + 1) + "is: " + strNumofPurchaseArray[intNewItemCounter]);
    intNewItemCounter++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays start at 0. You made a mistake on your 4th line, it should be 
    `strNumofPurchaseArray[intGroceryAmount] = strNewItemInput;`

You're creating an array of intGroceryAmount items but the highest index in the array is intGroceryAmount - 1 and the lowest is 0.

Comment: Yea thanks that problem is fixed now. But my loop is still not showing all the grocery list items. It mentions the last one, which is the new one only, and leaves the other ones blank
           while (intNewItemCounter < (intGroceryAmount + 1))
                    {
                        
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Grocery item #" + (intNewItemCounter + 1) + "is: " + strNumofPurchaseArray[intNewItemCounter]);
                        intNewItemCounter++;

                    }

Comment: This is the output, in case you were wondering
Grocery item #1 is: -blank-
Grocery item #2 is: -blank-
Grocery item #3 is: (new item input)

Comment: I don't write C# but shouldn't you initialise your intNewItemCounter to 0 before using it?
Try adding `intNewItemCounter = 0`

before your for loop. You should also consider using List's as the other people suggested (skip that if you're just following some kind of course on C#).

Comment: Yes, that was already declared before, this is a small part of a much bigger assignment, so all the declarations were done before, and it should not be a problem with the counter, because i am displaying the counter when I mention the grocery item#, which are all listed correctly, its just the next part, the items itself, that is not showing, except for the new one. And yes, I am not allowed to use List function, just plain simple arrays with other simple stuff, like ifs and loops

Comment: Ah yes I see, the problem is your making a new array, but you're not filling in the old values. When you assign you're array which is one element bigger than it used to be, copy over the contents of the old array into the new one using a for or while loop.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it..:D. Thanks to everyone else to take your time too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to resize your list then I would suggest using a `List<string>`, which will resize automatically when you call `Add`.  If you must stick with an array then you should probably look at the `Array.Resize` method for resizing, which will automatically copy the items from the old array into the new one as well.  You should then use a `foreach` loop to enumerate the items.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't work that way in C#. They work best when you know the size of the structure upfront. If you need to add and remove items dinamically, your best bet is the `List<T>` class

```
var strNumofPurchaseArray = new List<string>();
System.Console.WriteLine("What is the new item you wish to enter?");
strNewItemInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
strNumofPurchaseArray.Add(strNewItemInput);

System.Console.WriteLine("\nYour new list of Grocery item is shown below:\n");
for(int i=0; i< strNumofPurchaseArray.Count; i++)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("Grocery item #" + (i + 1) + "is: " + strNumofPurchaseArray[i]);
}
```